# 'CheckboxSelectMultiple' object has no attribute 'label'

Tags: python, django

I'm dynamically creating a form based on the number of skills in the database. It's created like so:

```
class FilterFreelancerForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FilterFreelancerForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        skills = Skill.objects.all()
        for skill in skills:
            self.fields['custom_%s' % skill] = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple()
```

My view simply instantiates the form object like so `form = FilterFreelancerForm()` and returns it to the template to be rendered with `{{form}}`. This causes the `AttributeError: 'CheckboxSelectMultiple' object has no attribute 'label'`.

Why is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CheckboxSelectMultiple is a widget, not a field.